# Resource for Recognizing Framework/CMS From URL or Other Clues?

Tags: url, frameworks

I'm curious to know which web framework or content management system a website is using based upon clues from the URL, headers, content.  Does anyone know of a resource on the web that would provide this?  For example:

- .html -> maybe a flat-file
- .php -> something built using PHP, perhaps.
- .jsp -> something using Java Server Pages
- .asp -> Active Server Pages
- 0,2097,1-1-1928,00 -> Vignette CMS
- .do -> ??

Thanks.

Comment: 0,2097,1-1-1928,00 is Vignette's web content management system.

Comment: thanks.  I was very curious about that one.

Answer (score 2):

Finding CMS by url

http://2ip.ru/cms/

enter URL in center input field and click big blue button below

Results in black - not found,
          in red - found

NOTE:
May play around with url path: with http://, with or without www. part -- results may differ.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not restricted to just the query string then there are a few other options.  For example to identify a rails app:

Script, stylesheet and image tags tend to have a 10 digits number appended (this allows you to cache, and still change the file):

```
<script src="/javascripts/all.js?1236037318" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also sometimes tell from the cookies what the framework is.  For example rails apps tend to have a session cookie called _appName_session, and often you can find a flash contained.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with your list there.  If all you want to know is the stack (LAMP, IIS, Java) then that's all you really need.

If querying the URL in question is an option, then you can usually pull the webserver make/version out of the HTTP response header as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nifty Chrome extension called [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg):

> Wappalyzer is a browser extension that uncovers the technologies used
>   on websites. It detects content management systems, eCommerce
>   platforms, web servers, JavaScript frameworks, analytics tools and
>   many more.